# Proving a vector from the pinhole camera

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

So I'm trying to prove a vector from the viewpoint of a pinhole camera to the vanishing point of a set of 3D parallel lines is parallel to the direction of the parallel lines. I figured proof by contradiction would help me understand all the geometric concepts together, but I feel like I'm missing a few steps:

Lets assume that a parallel set of 3D lines A,B, and C aren’t parallel to the vector from the viewpoint of a pinhole camera to the vanishing point. If so then there exists a point in which the vectors of the parallel lines touch the vector created from the view point of the pinhole camera to the vanishing point. If this is true, then there must be a point where the coordinates of the image plane and of the 3D world are exactly the same. But as this can't happen as the transformation between the two depends on the focal length and Z on the 3D plane, then the lines are parallel.

Comment: Hint: Give names to things. Call the viewpoint $E$, for "eye"; call the vanishing point $V$. If your definitions are anything like mine, then $V$ is a point on the *image plane*, a plane in 3-space. And you need to think about parallelism in this plane, *and* about parallelism in 3-space itself, to answer this kind of question.

Comment: @John Hughes So I was drawing this out, with making a point V on the image plane and putting the viewpoint E outside of the image plane to show the translation between the image and the 3D plane. So am I on the right track with creating a vector R as the connection between E and V and thatś what should be parallel with the 3D lines?

Comment: Well...sort of . Here's a general hint: take a bundle of parallel lines in 3-space. For each line, $m$, consider the plane $S_m$ containing $E$ and $m$. What can you say about the planes $S_m$? Well, they all contain $E$, of course. Can you say anything more, knowing that the line $m$ comes from a bundle of parallel lines?

Comment: Hmmm, each point p on the Sm plane that was created from line m wouldn´t touch the point v?

Comment: Indeed. So those planes all contain both $E$ and $V$.

Comment: Alright, hmmm.... I feel like thereś enough to whip up a proof but Iḿ just trying to figure out how to tie it all together cohesively.

Comment: Good! That's what you *should* be doing!

Comment: Err, yeah. U was just afraid that I was going in the wrong direction or that I wasn't saying anything correct.